# ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'project.Event' (errno: 150) *mySQL* create table error

Tags: mysql, linux, database

The following is a code snippet for a create table script that my team is using for a project. The script works on our server, but fails with the error 150 on my local machine, it is driving me mad.

(the script is a lot longer and includes drop table for all tables at the beginning)

```
/* Create Type table */
CREATE TABLE Types
    (typeID TINYINT not null,
     typeName VARCHAR (7) not null,
     PRIMARY KEY (typeID));

/* Create Event table */
CREATE TABLE Event
    (title VARCHAR (25) not null,
     typeID TINYINT not null,
     description VARCHAR (100),
     PRIMARY KEY (title),
     FOREIGN KEY (typeID) REFERENCES Types);
```

I've attempted to fix this through searching but every result I've come across says to check data-type, etc. The code looks good to me so I can't for the life of me figure it out. Any set of eyes to peak would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to inform `references` which field of the table while defining the foreign key

`FOREIGN KEY (typeID) REFERENCES Types(typeID));`